# Can I use Let's Encrypt to generate SSL Certificate even if I don't own the domain name

Tags: lets-encrypt

Can I use Let's Encrypt to generate SSL Certificate even if I don't own the domain name? The scenario is I have a site that lets user create their own sort of page inside my site which would be a subdomain under my main domain. Now, there's a feature that they can use their own domain name (using a different provider) that will point to the created page on my site so they can use any domain name that they want.

Will I still be able to provide SSL using Let's Encrypt to my user? Note: I'm new at this thing so I am not sure if I am asking the correct question, but I am asking as how I understand it right now.

Comment: Do your customers point their DNS at your webserver? In that case it might be possible

Comment: @chrki: I'm not sure what you mean, but can you elaborate what was on your mind, of it being possible?

Comment: I suppose your customers create DNS AAA records with their domain providers, they enter your server's IP address there, and you create some nginx/Apache virtual hosts on the server (maybe in a control panel like cPanel or similar) - is that how you configured it? In that case you can create certs for them. If they just create domain forwardings (they usually work with HTML frames, afaik) it won't work. You do have SSH access, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The validation occurs based on HTTP file retrieval or via DNS through TXT records.

I built [Greenlock](https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock-express.js) to be able to handle exactly that kind of use case. It will currently work for the scenario that you suggest and I plan to implement more DynDNS support in the future.